# Discord - How to update voice channel limit?

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to Discord bot development. I want to set the `user_limit` on an existing voice channel. I know the voice channel id I just want to update the limit there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific Python library specified so it's assumed to be [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py).

---

First, you will need to fetch the channel via your [Client class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) instance, like so:

```py
channel = client.get_channel(123)
```

- "123" is the channel ID, in `int` form.

That function will return the appropriate type of channel (or `None`), which means you can edit the `VoiceChannel` via [VoiceChannel.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.edit):

```py
await channel.edit(user_limit=2)
```

And done! If you need Discord's API reference, you can check it out [*in this site*](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#modify-channel-json-params-guild-channel).